# Automating removal of entries from an excel database/register

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first thing I've programmed since an intro to C++ class at university almost a decade ago so I hope this isn't too basic, but I've been stuck on it for quite a while now!

A quick background. I've got a "central" database of information on construction chemicals in it's own workbook. Each chemical has it's own row with a few safety notes and a hyperlink to a PDF. I've also set up another workbook which can be copied to any location on our server and still reference the central workbook and PDFs. This workbook acts as a register where while chemicals are on a construction site they're quickly added to a list (copies over all the info and PDF link from central WB and copies the PDF file into the same folder as the workbook). I'm stuck on how to remove those entries from the register once a chemical is removed from site.

Ideally this will delete the information across the row, move the other entries up to fill the gap, and delete the PDF from the folder. I'm confident I can do the two second things, but I can't figure out how to delete a row with a couple of clicks.

I've attempted adding buttons or checkboxes using VBA that are linked to a cell in the row and going from there, but I've had a lot of issues, ranging from not being able to position them correctly, to not being able to automate linking them to a cell.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    'Copies SDS PDF to job folder

Dim fso As Object                       'For moving file
Dim FileName As String                  'Pdf file name
Dim Dest As String                      'Job folder location
Dim RegRow As Integer                   'First empty row in register
Dim Hyper As Range
Set CopyRange = Sheet3.Range("O4", "R4") 'From Vlookup on sheet 3 to add to register


    If (Sheet1.Cells(5, 1) = "") Or (Sheet3.Cells(4, 9) = "") Then       'Checks for a match in vlookup on sheet 3
                                                                         'and that something has been entered
        MsgBox "Please select a product to add to the job register"

        Exit Sub

    ElseIf (Sheet1.Cells(18, 16) <> "OK") Then                           'Checks for duplicates using Vlookup on sheet1 (hidden)

        MsgBox "Product already added to register"

        Exit Sub

    Else

        RegRow = Sheet1.Range("A999").End(xlUp).Row + 1                     'Finds empty row
        Set PasteRange = Sheet1.Range(Cells(RegRow, 1), Cells(RegRow, 4))   'Assigns empty cells in register to variable
        FileName = Sheet3.Range("E1").Text
        Dest = Sheet3.Range("A1").Text
        Hyper = Sheet1.Range(Cells(RegRow, 5))

        Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")            'Moves PDF

        Call fso.CopyFile(FileName, Dest, True)                             'Moves PDF

        PasteRange.Value = CopyRange.Value                                  'Copies register info to front page
        Sheet3.Range("S4").Copy
        Sheet1.Cells(RegRow, 5).Select
        Hyper.Paste


            'Add checkbox to new entry
            'Dim CheckBoxCell As Range
            'CheckBoxCell = Sheet1.Range(Cells(RegRow, 6))

            'Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=CheckBoxCell.Left, Top:=CheckBoxCell.Top, Width:=CheckBoxCell.Width, Height:=CheckBoxCell.Height, _
             '   LinkedCell = Sheet1.Cells(RegRow, 16), Caption = "Select"

    End If

End Sub
```

Please excuse the references to Vlookup cells, this is my first foray into writing macros so I've got a bit of a mixture of techniques to make it work.

Ideally some help with a simple way to do this, or to code for checkboxes/buttons that will remove a row, the rest I think I can figure out.

Comment: I should also note that this needs to be easy because it's for often somewhat tech illiterate construction workers to use, not just myself.

Comment: Why are you jumping through hoops? Delete the row, and then let Excel shiff the rows below. `    Rows("3:3").Select` (replace the coordinates with the actual row, or use the user's selected row), followed by `Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` to move all the rows below it up. You can figure a lot of these things out by just recording a macro in Excel - start recording, do what you need to do, stop recording, and then edit the macro to see the code Excel generated, which you can then modify as needed.

Comment: Actually Rows(3).Delete is what you need. Never use .Select or Selection in VBA - they are evil and should be removed from the language!

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I really appreciate your input. If it was just for me I would definitely just delete the rows and carry on, but I'm trying to make this spreadsheet for other people to manage their chemical registers. I'd like to use a checkbox --> "remove selected" button, or "remove" button so that the UI is as simple as possible. Failing that I can just write instructions saying "select the row etc", but I was hoping to avoid it.